# Set JPanel background transparent, setOpaque() doesn't let me paint

Tags: java, swing, transparency, paint, paintcomponent

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tetris extends JFrame {

public Tetris() {

    add(new GamePanel());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(800, 600);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Tetris");
}

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {


    public GamePanel(){
        TetrisBoard tetraBoard= new TetrisBoard();
        GridBagLayout layout= new GridBagLayout();
        this.setLayout(layout);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.ipadx = 190;
        c.ipady = 390;
        c.insets.left= 360;
        layout.setConstraints(tetraBoard, c);
        this.add(tetraBoard);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g){
       super.paint(g);

       g.setFont(new Font("Birth Std", Font.PLAIN, 12));
       g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
       g.drawString("200", 36, 63);
       g.drawString("200", 36, 88);
       g.drawString("200", 36, 114);
    }

}//GamePanel class

public class TetrisBoard extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    private Thread animator= new Thread(this);
    private final int DELAY= 50;

    public TetrisBoard(){
        setFocusable(true);
        //setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        //this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
        animator = new Thread(this);
        animator.start();
    }//addNotify


   @Override
   public void paint (Graphics g){
       super.paint(g);
       g.drawRect (20, 30, 130, 50);

   }//paint

   @Override
public void run() {
    long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

    beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (true) {
        repaint();

        timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
        sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;

        if (sleep < 0)
            sleep = 2;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
} 

}//TetrisBoard class


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tetris t = new Tetris();
}
```

}

With this code the result is that it doesn't paint anything at all. I just want the background to be transparent not the images painted over the background, but it looks like the paint method doesn't paint if I setOpaque(false).

Edit: as requested I posted a simple code, TetraBoard is added to the GamePanel (using that GridBagLayout), and GamePanel is added to the frame, those 3 classes are separate files. I want TetraBoard to have a transparent background, so that I can see the background of GamePanel, but what I paint on tetraboard must be visible. If I setOpaque(false), TetraBoard is transparent, but it set on transparent everything I paint on it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  In a `JPanel`, override `paintComponent(Graphics)` rather than `paint(Graphics)`

Comment: I posted a simple code, I tried to use paintComponent instead of paint, but I have the same result.

Comment: *"I posted a simple code.."* I recommended (and will look at) an **SSCCE.**  Also, the `JPanel` ***still*** overrides `paint()`!  Are you capable of reading all the way to the end of a sentence? Of following a link and reading the content?

Comment: I have to agree with Andrew. Your problem is one of misbehavior, and it would be *much* easier for us to help you if we were able to fully understand this misbehavior by seeing it for ourselves, by having code that we can compile, run, modify, and hopefully correct, a program that is small enough so as not to drown us in too much unrelated code so we can't see the forest for the trees, yet large enough to be compilable and runnable, in short, an sscce.

Comment: Sorry for the previous code. Now the only difference with the original code is that I don't use images but I draw a rectangle. The code that I posted works, but my orginal code doesn't. I used paintComponent but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** Assuming I understand what you're trying to do, replace the following line in the TetrisBoard constructor:

```
setOpaque(false);
```

with:

```
setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

Comment: Since he's calling `setOpaque(false)`, your recommendation to call `setBackground(...)` won't work. I'd venture to say that it is impossible to give a good recommendation until the original poster gives more necessary information.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The OP has posted 'more information' in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { // as suggested Andrew
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawArc(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 360); // arc will be painted on transparent bg
    }
};
p.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); // as suggested Perry
...
```

So, you have to do two actions:
1) override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` of JPanel
2) and set bg color to transparent: `new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)`